a comparable macro to "\eval"
I luckily found a macros written by Joseph Wright which is most closest to eval function in numerica package. However eval can be used with two different forms. First one is eval{$ $} which prints formula and its result , the other is \eval{} which prints result only. How to make \printandcalc behave like that ? Link to printandcalc Calculating the value of a formula without duplication, using LuaTeX or similar
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xparse,numerica}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \printandcalc } { m }
  {  #1 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
      \cs_set:Npx \__cs_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__cs_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\eval{$\pi/2+10$} (eval with \$ \$) % print formula and its result

$\printandcalc{\pi/2+10}$ (printandcalc) % can also print formula and its result, but how to make it \printandcalc{$\pi/2+10$} ?

\eval{\pi/2+10}  (eval without \$ \$) % print result directly
%\printandcalc{\pi/2+10} % not work without math environment

\end{document}


You can use the \ifmmode TeX primitive:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xparse,numerica}

\def\printandcalc#1{\ifmmode #1=\fi{\def\pi{pi}\fpeval{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\eval{$\pi/2+10$} (eval with \$ \$) % print formula and its result

$\printandcalc{\pi/2+10}$ (printandcalc) % can also print formula and its result, but how to make

\eval{\pi/2+10}  (eval without \$ \$) % print result directly

\printandcalc{\pi/2+10} % works without math environment

\end{document}

